# How to navigate to another viewcontroller with PUSH style from UITabBarController page

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

First of all, I'm a beginner. forgive me for this stupid question.

I make two child pages using`UITabBarController`, the first page including a`UIButton`, and alsl I make a another page (DetailPage). I connectted the button and`DetailPage` with segue. but the style of segue cannot be setted to `push`.(this will trigger a error , `push` style only used for`UINavigatorController`).

So, when I click the button , how to navigate to DetailPage with PUSH style?

I try a new method, Using`UINavigatorController` to manage first page and DetailPage, and then make this`UINavigatorController` embed into`UITabItem`. when I finish this, I can navigate to DetailPage with `push` style. But another question occured, when navigating DetailPage , the TabBar is always stay the bottom of page. I wanna all`UITabBarController` will be pushed to left side.

The effect what I want like this picture:
[image]

How can I optimize my code?

Comment: Your set up seems fine.. to conditionally hide the bottom tab bar just set `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true;` in the detail page view controller's view will appear and set it to `false` in view will appear method on the first view controller...

Answer (score 0):

Implement delegate(UITabBarControllerDelegate) method like this :

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSArray *tabViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;
    UIView * fromView = tabBarController.selectedViewController.view;
    UIView * toView = viewController.view;
    if (fromView == toView)
        return false;
    NSUInteger fromIndex = [tabViewControllers indexOfObject:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    NSUInteger toIndex = [tabViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    [UIView transitionFromView:fromView
                        toView:toView
                      duration:0.3
                       options: toIndex > fromIndex ? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        if (finished) {
                            tabBarController.selectedIndex = toIndex;
                        }
                    }];
    return true;
}
```

This is for flip animationJust change animation

For Push :

```
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    [transition setDuration:0.3];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    [transition setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
    [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
```

For Pop :

```
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    [transition setDuration:0.3];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [transition setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
    [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
```

Now Its up to you, best of luck....

Comment: Perhaps your solution is used for navigating from one to another viewcontroller both in tabBarController.
I got it with  `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Sorry!! I misunderstood it. :( As per my understanding, you want to change tab with push pop animations. By the way congrats !!!